# org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException WELD-001409: Ambiguous dependencies for type X with qualifiers @Default

Tags: java, jboss, cdi, qualifiers

I followed the doc (https://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/injection.html) to create qualifiers, now I'm getting a deployment error in wildfly-10.1.0.Final, I red a lot of similar questions on the internet but still no clue.
The code could compile and injections work well for other classes.

Here's the error:

```
"{
    \"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services\" => {\"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"test.war\\\".WeldStartService\" => \"org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"test.war\\\".WeldStartService: Failed to start service
    Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: Exception List with 2 exceptions:
Exception 0 :
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001409: Ambiguous dependencies for type MessageSender with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject @B private test.AccessService.messageSenderB
  at test.AccessService.MessageSenderB(AccessService.java:0)
  Possible dependencies:
  - Managed Bean [class test.messagesender.impl.MessageSenderBImpl] with qualifiers [@Any @Default],
  - Managed Bean [class test.messagesender.impl.MessageSenderAImpl] with qualifiers [@Any @Default]
```

Here are the classes:

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ TYPE, METHOD, PARAMETER, FIELD })
@Documented
public @interface A{}
```

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ TYPE, METHOD, PARAMETER, FIELD })
@Documented
public @interface B{}
```

```
public interface MessageSender {}
```

```
@Singleton
@A
public class MessageSenderAImpl implements MessageSender {}
```

```
@Singleton
@B
public class MessageSenderBImpl implements MessageSender {}
```

```
@Singleton
public class AccessService {
    @Inject
    @A
    private MessageSender messageSenderA;

    @Inject
    @B
    private MessageSender messageSenderB;
```

Seems the first injection worked, the second one failed. Any idea?

Comment: Can you make double sure that the qualifiers are part of the deployment during runtime? Because the exception suggests they aren't present/visible.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found it.

The stupid IDE auto imported the Qualifier class from spring framework

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
```

thought the correct one to use is

```
import javax.inject.Qualifier;
```